# Are the QtGlobal declarations accessible in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm attempting to use the some of the functions in the [QtGlobal Header File](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html), but cannot identify where they are. Namely, the qMax and qMin functions.

I've tried using it in the following ways:

```
qMax(190, fontHeight * 12)
QtCore.qMax(190, fontHeight * 12)
QtGui.qMax(190, fontHeight * 12)
QtWidgets.qMax(190, fontHeight * 12)
```

The first method has the following response:

```
NameError: name 'qMax' is not defined
```

The final 3 all have essentially the same error, just with `QtCore` substituted with whichever module I was attempting to import them from.

```
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'qMax'
```

I cannot see why these functions would not be included somewhere, but I just can't figured out how to use them.

So are they included, and if so, how do I call them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QtGlobal functions are in the QtCore module, but not everything is included:

```
>>> print(' '.join(x for x in dir(QtCore) if x[0] == 'q'))
qAbs qAddPostRoutine qAddPreRoutine qChecksum qCompress qCritical qDebug
qErrnoWarning qFatal qFloatDistance qFormatLogMessage qFuzzyCompare qInf
qInstallMessageHandler qIsFinite qIsInf qIsNaN qIsNull qQNaN
qRegisterResourceData qRemovePostRoutine qRound qRound64 qSNaN
qSetFieldWidth qSetMessagePattern qSetPadChar qSetRealNumberPrecision
qSharedBuild qUncompress qUnregisterResourceData qVersion qWarning
qrand qsrand
```

There seems little point in including `qMin` and `qMax`. Python already has `min` and `max`, which offer a far superior API.

PS:

I suppose I should add that `min/max` will work fine with Qt types, so long as they implement the less-than operator (`__lt__`):

```
>>> x = QtGui.QStandardItem('1')
>>> y = QtGui.QStandardItem('2')
>>> min(x, y).text()
'1'
>>> max(x, y).text()
'2'
```